# RoR date modified of particular field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my RoR app when a particular field (`telephone_preference`) is updated/changed I want to record the date/time and current_user (using devise gem) in two fields called `tel_modifided_date` and `tel_modified_user`.

Not sure how to trigger the update.

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Comment: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail is a good gem for tracking changes to models

Answer (score 1):

In your controller#update method you should have something like this...

```
def update
  @record.assign_attributes(params) 
  if @record.telephone_preference_changed?
    @record.tel_modifided_date = Time.now
    @record.tel_modified_user = current_user 
  end

  if @record.save
    # redirect for success
  else
    # add code to return error 
  end
end
```

Checkout https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/assign_attributes and https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty for more details.

Comment: I wrote a concern for reacting to specific attribute changes, that does this as a side effect, it might make a useful example https://gist.github.com/robomc/fa6c2371fe8cab890b7503baffb1c784